# How do I change the default ObjectId MongoDB creates with NextAuth.js?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

NextAuth comes with a MongoDB Adapter that creates accounts upon successful login. I would like to change the default object the adapter produces, atleast the userId it generates to something else, but I can't find anything about this in documentation.

Is there anyway to do this?

I have looking everywhere in documentation. I don't know what to try.